# JavaScript checkbox onclick function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I am stuck at the simple JavaScript function, related to the checkbox validation. I need to document.write if the cb1 is checked, and the same if cb2. And if both, or one of them isn't checked, then write nothing.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>TEST PAGE</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="submit.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="width:100%"><input type="checkbox" id="cb1"></div>
    <div style="width:100%"><input type="checkbox" id="cb2"></div>

    <div style="width:100%"><input type="submit" name="execute" id="execute" value="Execute" onClick="run();"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

submit.js

```
function run() {

    document.write('<div>' + "HERE GOES YOUR CHECKBOX CHOICE: " + '</div>');

    if(document.getElementById("cb1").checked == true) {
        document.write("This is check box 1");
    }
    if(document.getElementById("cb2").checked == true) {
        document.write("This is check box 2");
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem you're having? Are you looking for a jQuery solution? You used the tag but no jQuery code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an improved run function:

```
function run() {

    var snip = "<div>HERE GOES YOUR CHECKBOX CHOICE: </div>";

    if(document.getElementById("cb1").checked == true) {
        snip += "<br/>This is check box 1";
    }
    if(document.getElementById("cb2").checked == true) {
        snip += "This is check box 2";
    }
    document.write(snip);
}
```

Everyone  spotted the error of overwriting you html before actually reading the elements, so that was the cause of your error, clearing the DOM and then trying to read an input property that no longer exists.

Answer (score 1):

you shouldnt use document.write.
use append to tags
like

```
$("#divid").append($("<input/>",{type:"checkbox",onclick:"yourfunction(this)"}));
```

Answer (score 0):

just use `.checked` in javascript in jquery use `.prop('checked')`

```
function run() {    

if(document.getElementById("cb1").checked) {
    document.write("<div>This is check box 1</div>");
}
if(document.getElementById("cb2").checked) {
    document.write("<div>This is check box 2</div>");
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (document.getElementById('cb1').checked && document.getElementById('cb2').checked) {
    // both are checked
}
else {
   // only one or none are checked
}
```

As was mentioned in one of the previous answers, you should not use `document.write`. You can use `.append(string)` to add things to the document:

```
document.append('Both boxes are checked');
```